# How to cast a char * to int, and then back to char * in C programming?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, reference

How do I cast a char * into an int, and read it back into a char *? For example if some char * data is loaded into memory, and knowing the memory addresses from an int variable, read them back. In my case, I cannot add additional header/libraries, except for stdio.h

Code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
        //first example
        char * const argv[] = {"first", "second", "third", NULL};
        unsigned long int addr1 = &argv[1]; //holds the address of 'second'
        void * addr2 = argv[1]; //same as above

        printf("&argv[1] is %x\n",&argv[1]);
        printf("addr1 is %x\n",addr1);
        printf("dereferenced addr2 is %s\n",((char*)addr2)); //why does this work
        printf("dereferenced addr1 is %s\n",((char* const*)addr1)[0]); //why does this work, and not char*(addr1)
        printf("argv[1] is %s\n",argv[1]);

        //second example
        char * text = "testing";
        unsigned long int addr3 = &text;

        printf("text is %s\n", text);
        printf("address3 is %x\n", addr3);
        printf("address of text is %x\n", &text);
        printf("addr3 is %s\n", ((char*)addr3));

        return 0;
}
```

And the output I get is as follows

```
&argv[1] is 1f143378
addr1 is 1f143378
dereferenced addr2 is second //dont understand this either
dereferenced addr1 is second //I dont understand how this works though
argv[1] is second            //expected output, normal

text is testing              //as expected
address3 is 1f143350         //as expected
address of text is 1f143350  //as expected
addr3 is G@                  //incorrect, I dont understand this output
```

Problem which I am having is, the memory location must be in an integer variable, not `void *`. dereferencing `void *` seems pretty easy and straightforward, but in this case, I definitely need to dereference from `int addr1`, or `int addr3`

How do I make `(char*)addr3` work? To correctly dereference the memory location from `unsigned long int` to `char *` and display 'testing'. In this case, without using `void *`

In addition, in the case of `char * const argv[] = {"first", "second", "third", NULL};`, since `unsigned long int addr1` holds the memory location of 'second', why can't I use `(char*)addr2` to directly dereference it?

Thanks!

**EDIT
The main purpose which I am driving here is extracting information off memory locations found in system registers. Say `char * const argv[] = {...}` is stored in memory, and this pointer `argv` is currently stored in one of the system/CPU registers. Reading from the register would give a memory address e.g. `0x1f143370`, which I save it to a variable `int`? From here on, with a known assumption that it contains a `char *`, I would want to dereference it.

Comment: There's no guarantee that an `int` can hold a converted pointer value without losing information. Exactly why do you need to do this? The obvious solution is to use pointers, not intended, to hold pointer values.

Comment: Here is why your third output line printed `second`. `argv[]` is an array of pointers to string literals. You assigned the second array element to `addr2` with `void * addr2 = argv[1];` and you then passed this pointer to `printf` to satisfy its format spec `%s`. The next line also printed `second` because you assigned the address of `argv[1]` element to `addr1`, which you then passed the `0th` element of that pointer array to `printf`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: For example, on iOS and MacOS X 64 bit version there is a guarantee that an int __cannot__ hold a converted pointer other than a null pointer.

Comment: right, I understand the confusion, the main reason why I am doing this (dereferencing from an `int`) is because my ultimate aim is to extract information off raw memory locations.
Say in the command `./a.out firstarg secondarg`, this array of string literals are being pointed by the `RSI` register. Reading from the register will give me an integer which holds the memory location where this array is stored. Thus, this is why, from an integer which holds the address of a memory location, I need to extract out the relevant information, in this case, a `char *`

Comment: @klx123: What exactly do you mean by "raw memory locations"? In what form are you given these locations? Ideally you should be given them as `void*` pointer values.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Strictly speaking `argv` is a pointer, not an array, but it does point to the first element of an array of pointers. Each pointer in that array points to a string, not to a string literal (which is a source code construct).

Comment: @KeithThompson I take your first point, even though `char * const argv[] = {"first", "second", "third", NULL};` is clearly creating an array. But please explain why `"second"` is a *string* and not a *string literal*.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Certainly `"second"` is a string literal -- but it exists only in the program's source code, not during execution. I hadn't noticed that `argv` is not the usual parameter to `main`, but the distinction between a (source file) string literal and a (run time) string is still important.

Comment: @KeithThompson I thought that `"second"` does exist at runtime in initialised memory, whether it is used in this case as the object of a pointer, or in another case, say `char deuce[] = "second";` and is called a string literal because it cannot be modified.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No, a string literal is a construct in a source file. It includes the quotation marks, which do not exist at run time. And given `char deuce [] = "second"; `, the contents of `deuce ` *can* be modified at run time.

Comment: @KeithThompson of course it can be modified, I was giving another example of the use of a string literal. And obviously the quotes are not retained. But if `char deuce[] = "second";` initialises a local variable it will have to be initialised every time the function is called, therefore the literal string resides somewhere in the executable. So I still can't fathom your remark as to why is doesn't.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Because a *string literal* is by definition a construct in C source code. It doesn't exist at run time any more than the `{` and `}` symbols surrounding a block do. The string literal `"second"` (consisting of 8 characters) exists only in some source file. It results in an anonymous *array object* of type `char[7]` that exists while the program is being executed (if it's not optimized away); that object contains a *string* (not a *string literal*). See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.4.5 for *string literals*, 7.1.1p1 for *strings*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* string = "42";
    int num = 0;

    sscanf(string, "%i", &num);

    char string2[12];
    sprintf(string2, "%i", num);

    printf("num is %i\n", num);
    printf("string2 is %s\n", string2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
num is 42
string2 is 42
```